# How to retrieve user permissions? (crud system)

Tags: php, mysql, permissions

I can't find any good method to get my user's permissions

I used multiple SQL queries to get the user data based on their role but I don't like the idea of asking the permission every time the user clicks on something... but I also dislike the idea of getting all the permissions from SQL and set it all in the "session"
There are at least 12 columns (permissions). I use 4 tables, users, users_role, roles and finally permissions

```
//... 
$permissions = sqlSelect($conn, '
SELECT * FROM permissions
INNER JOIN roles
ON permissions.role_id = roles.id
INNER JOIN users_role
ON permissions.role_id = users_role.role_id
WHERE users_role.user_id = ?', 'i', $row['id']);

$user_permissions = array();

while ($permission_row = $permissions->fetch_assoc()) {
  unset($permission_row['id_role']);
  $user_permissions[] = $permission_row;
}

$_SESSION['logged'] = true;
$_SESSION['user_permissions'] = $user_permissions;

//...
```

Comment: Clearly you need to retrieve the permissions from the database at some stage. The only way, not to have to do that every time during an user session, is to store them with the session. There's nothing wrong with that. So the obvious question to you is: Why do you not like to store the permissions in a session? Note that you didn't explain this in your question.

Comment: Because if I set the user's permissions while login, and then I want to delete or change their role (any reason) the user would still have the old permissions in their session. So i don't know wich method is the best to avoid that kind of stuff

Comment: OK, that is a good reason. You also don't want to read the permissions/roles from the database every time, to keep them up to date. A solution to this could be an extra field in the database, associated with the user. It indicates the last time a permission/role of that user was changed. Now you only need to check this field: If the latest edit is later than the one you stored with the permissions/roles in the session you need to reread all of them from the database, if not then you can still use those stored in the session.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as opinion-based: you seem to already be aware of the two main approaches, and the trade-offs of each. You haven't really given a specific problem, just a general dissatisfaction with those trade-offs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use session.
first retrieve permissions from mysql and store them in a session.
then use session to check permissions.
and finally when a user logged out. clear this session.

Comment: Yeah, but it is possible to destroy some user's session if I delete or change the role using and admin role? The reason why I dislike using sessions is because the permissions are saved while login, so if the user is deleted, or their role changes, they are still having access

Comment: i know that. i had a website that when a user complete a level a new permission was granted to that user.
so i had to refresh user permission while a user logged in
for solving that problem i used a function that was responsible for refresh user permission. so when admin delete a user(or other changes happen that affect the user permission)  it has to call that function.

Comment: _"i used a function that was responsible for refresh user permission. so when admin delete a user(or other changes happen that affect the user permission) it has to call that function."_ - How would you determine when it should call that function or not while a user is logged in? If you call it on every request, then you're doing what the OP said they want to avoid (read the permissions on every request).

Comment: you don't need to call it on every request.
you only call the refreshPermission function when an admin role change or delete a user's permission. ( you probably have a function that when an admin change a user role this function get executed. you call  refreshPermission  at the end of this function)
the only function that you need to call it on every request is the function that get permission from session. 
do you want me to right a simple example?

Comment: implementing my suggestion is triky
i belive KIKO Software suggestion is very easy to implement just add a filed that indicate a user permission has changed or not(on every request)?
if answer is yes . then read all user's permission from db 
and if answer is no. then proceed with current session